# Is it possible to create a role in Drupal which only has permission to edit pages in a certain language?

Tags: drupal, internationalization

Our Drupal site supports multiple languages and I would like to allow our language experts the ability to customize the individual pages, but I would like to avoid giving them access to the English language originals. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Translation Access](http://drupal.org/project/i18n_access) module. I never used it myself, but it seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: That does seem like it should work. I've actually managed to get something working with the basic system, but this does seem easier.

Comment: Actually, I think I've finally settled on using the Translation Management module. Works pretty well. I had some trouble with the Translation Access module, but I think that might be an artifact with how we have setup our site.